# "Seeing" in weather forecasts

Tags: tense, present-continuous, emphasis

I know that the verb *to see* can be used in the Present Continuous tense if it means:

1. to visit/to meet someone: *I'm seeing my dentist tomorrow* (I've got an appointment).
2. to watch (a movie/concert/play/sports game): *I'm seeing a cool film now!* (interestingly, The [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/see) Dictionary says that we cannot use the verb in any Continuous tense if it means *to watch*; though many people don't seem to know or care about it)
3. to date someone: *I was seeing her but I wasn't her committed boyfriend.*

But I don't quite understand why TV meteorologists often use the verb *to see* in the Present Continuous. Check out the video ([2:53](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oje0uW2Y-h8)):

> Off the Atlantic high pressure will continue to expand through the Iberian Peninsula and will start to create things rather calm. But **we are still seeing** some of those waves out there picking up to 5 meters on the coast of Portugal.

In her next (!) sentence ([3:01](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oje0uW2Y-h8)), the meteorologist says:

> Throughout much of North America **we're still seeing** rather clear skies.

To me it sounds emphatic but ungrammatical.

Is it really ungrammatical or is it just my sensation? If it is grammatical, why is *to see* used in the Present Continuous tense?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that the idea can be expressed, both of them grammatical:

> Throughout much of North America, we can still see rather clear skies.

Here, we *can* see clear skies *if* we look at them.

> Throughout much of North America we're still seeing rather clear skies.

Here, we *are* looking at the skies and what we are *seeing* is that they are clear.

---

In reality, both versions of the sentence, in conversational speech, convey the same thing:

> (Pointing to a graphic.) "Look! Clear skies!"

So, the difference I ascribe to the two is not really something that most people think about. Either version is fine.